# Send X_CSRF Token from Yii application to Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api, yii, csrf

I am trying to make an `API` call from `Yii 2` web application to an API that is developed in `Laravel`. Now Laravel expects an `X_CSRF` token whenever a `POST` request is made. I sent the `csrf` token generated by `Yii` with the request but Laravel API doesn't accept it. Now, How can I send X_CSRF token with the API call?

**CODE**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://endpoint.url");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    http_build_query([
                        'phone' => Yii::$app->session->get('number'),
                        'first_name' => $model->first_name,
                        'last_name' => $model->last_name,
                        'email' => $model->email,
                        'password' => $model->passcode,
                        'x_csrf' => $_csrf
                    ]));

// receive server response ...
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                print_r($server_output);
```

This is the Output:

> {"title":"Unauthorized
>   Request","detail":{"type":"invalid_x_csrf_token","message":"Invalid
>   x-csrf token provided"},"code":401}

Comment: Can you share the code your have so far?

Comment: Sure @MrMush, I have updated the question.

Comment: Laravel only accepts its own CSRF token. If you want to use laravel as an API you should probably stop doing CSRF and start doing 3rd party authentication like OAuth or JWT. Alternatively  you can ask for laravel to send the token it expects via a GET request.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the guidance.